# How to access to external db with user?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, external-connection

i'm a little bit lost about how to connect to an external server db.

So basically I create a user with the following query:

CREATE USER 'remote1'@'web-server-ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db_test.* TO 'remote1'@'web-server-ip' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

When I try to connect from the webserver it says
Database 'db_test' does not exist or specified database server user does not have privileges to access this database.

What I'm doing wrong?

Also if I try to import a db on the db server it does not allow me to do that, should I create a new user but with @localhost? and grand privileges with the 'web-server-ip'?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you connecting to the database?

Comment: You should not open a database port to public internet, it causes security risks. Use SSH port forwarding to access the server remotely.

Comment: @MichaelHampton with mysql -h db-server -p database -u remote1